# MySQL Point in Polygon Queries and DB Setup

Tags: mysql, sql, gis, spatial-query, point-in-polygon

I am trying to set up a table which consists of regions as [POLYGON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-polygon.html). I want to be able to query the table to find whether a given [POINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-point.html) lies in any of the stored regions or not.

I read that MySQL spatial extensions provide two types of functions to operate with geometries:

- [ST_*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains) for operating on object shapes
- [MBR*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-mysql-specific.html) for operating on minimum bounding rectangles

I tried following what worked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662910/search-a-table-for-point-in-polygon-using-mysql?rq=1). Here's how I set up my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `region` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`rpolygon` polygon NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I inserted a few records in the table after getting the polygon definitions from QGIS. I learned about inserting spatial records into a table from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/populating-spatial-columns.html). Here's how I inserted a record in the table

```
SET @g= ST_GeomFromText('Polygon ((-117.84293016891291472 33.64825334189644224, -117.8428418279120109 33.64599663087331294, -117.84048874488789238 33.64467151585973426, -117.84002294688312418 33.64517746886491523, -117.83983020288114574 33.64549067786812486, -117.83981414088098916 33.64605284787388939, -117.83983823388122403 33.64646242887808825, -117.84012734988419879 33.64708081588442212, -117.84053693088839054 33.64743417988804453, -117.84130790689629009 33.6479401328932326, -117.84199054190328582 33.64815696989545302, -117.84243224690781915 33.64822121789610776, -117.84293016891291472 33.64825334189644224))');
INSERT INTO region 
VALUES(1, 'NORTH-EAST', @g);
```

Just to do sanity check, I tried running a Point in Polygon query using various methods - MBRContains, ST_Contains etc, all of which result in no results or NULL. Below is a sample query that I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM region where ST_Contains(rpolygon, ST_GeomFromText('Point(33.646201 -117.841949)'));
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. Am I storing the values incorrectly, do you set up a geo table in a different way?, or am I querying incorrectly. I couldn't find any good tutorials online or examples that I could follow to do such a setup. Any pointers will be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Damn! I feel pretty stupid! The order of the coordinates is wrong in my query where I define the POINT.

Anyway. I hope this serves as a good short tutorial for anyone wanting to get started with Point-in-Polygon queries with mysql